# Bulk and Batch Rest API to get object values

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Do we have bulk and batch Rest API to get the customer service object (like contacts,accounts,partner etc) values. If yes, Please provide detailed information. It will helpful for us.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by bulk and batch?
Do you mean to reduce the API calls to fetch these objects individually and just call one API to fetch expanded Case along with the Contacts, Accounts, Partner etc?
Please give an example of what you need in the API is input and output.

Comment: yes, we need to execute the multiple API's using single API (like batch process)

Answer (score -1):

There is 2 ways to go about doing this:

1. You can use the **Table API** (bad, but hey that is OOTB). Look up
   for **REST API Explorer** and select the **Table API** in the **API
   Name** to fetch multiple records from a table from ServiceNow, or;
2. You can create your own REST API (better) to basically return
   what ever you want...